# AcountingJs: Converting string into currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency-formatting, accounting.js

I'm using [AccountingJs](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/) to format currency, but not always the values that work are in the house of thousands. I also need to convert variables to hundreds, like $ 234.45

The problem is that this and other plugins and JS methods I've tried always convert the values into thousands, never into hundreds.

I am using the value 17652 as an example, but:

```
Accounting.formatMoney (17652); // returns 17,652
```

Does anyone know of any way I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not divide by `100` before passing to your function?

Comment: @BenM I'd be uneasy about doing that. You can end up with strings like `84399.9999999999` when you do floating-point operations like this. For example, `0.06+0.01` gives `0.06999999999999999`. Having said that, I've failed to find an example of an `n` such that `n/100` is displayed wrongly in my browser (Firefox on Linux).

Comment: BenM: Its like David said. I tried, but I got the same result without cents...

Answer (score -1):

According to the AccountingJS documentation, you'd need to supply the decimal place.  http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Original Number:

123.5

will appear with AccountingJS:

123.50

Other than that you'll need to only supply 3 numbers to keep it in the hundreds.  The amount of numbers you're supplying will always come out as thousands since you don't supply the decimal.

Comment: Yeah, but my currency format is diferent (00.000,00) and the value I get is a integer...

Comment: Just for future reference, you should mention that in your post.  There is no way I could of inferred that information.